# Exim4 Configuration of Maildir Delivery

Tags: freebsd, exim

Documentation online is rather sparse on how to go about configuring Exim4 to use the Maildir delivery method instead of the default mbox format. This is on a FreeBSD system with Exim4 compiled from ports. Can anyone point to some documentation or tips for this?

Answer (score 2):

in your local_delivery section remove "file = xxx" and add the following:

```
  directory = $home/Maildir
  maildir_format
  maildir_use_size_file
```

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD, take a look at /usr/local/share/doc/exim/spec.txt for a copy of The Exim Specification which is pretty exhaustive.  This is the same doc that is available online in HTML, PDF and various other formats, but Exim makes the .txt output a first class citizen, not just a web-page dump, so it's highly usable.

You should search that for references to maildir, which would also lead you to read "[26.5 Maildir delivery](https://exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_appendfile_transport.html#SECTmaildirdelivery)"; from there, you might learn about Maildir++ and some of the enhancements to Maildir which are commonly supported to improve performance by encoding information into the filename, auto-create sub-directories, and more.